# Swift create table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I usually work with MVC, HTML and JavaScript. And I am therefore use to use HTML tables. I have made an iOS app in xcode, written in Swift, and it shows the table, through a custom cell(Following code):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    //Load cell

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StatModelViewCell
    //Map data
    let data = TableData.ListOfStatsModels[indexPath.row]

    if(Landscape == true)
    {
        //Map data to elements
        cell.LabelMemberName.text = data.MemberName
        cell.LabelGP.text = "GP:" + String(data.GP)
        cell.LabelW.text = "W:" + String(data.W)
        cell.LabelD.text = "D:" + String(data.D)
        cell.LabelL.text = "L:" + String(data.L)


        cell.LabelGoalsScorePositive.hidden = false
        cell.LabelGoalsScorePositive.text = "+" + String(data.GoalsScorePositive)
        cell.LabelGoalsScoreNegative.hidden = false
        cell.LabelGoalsScoreNegative.text = "-" + String(data.GoalsScoreNegative)
        cell.LabelP.hidden = false
        cell.LabelP.text = "P:" + String(data.P)
        cell.LabelP_GP.hidden = false
        cell.LabelP_GP.text = "P/GP:" + String(data.P_GP)
    }
    else
    {
        //Map data to elements
        cell.LabelMemberName.text = data.MemberName
        cell.LabelGP.text = "GP:" + String(data.GP)
        cell.LabelW.text = "W:" + String(data.W)
        cell.LabelD.text = "D:" + String(data.D)
        cell.LabelL.text = "L:" + String(data.L) + " P/GP:" + String(data.P_GP)

        cell.LabelGoalsScorePositive.hidden = true
        cell.LabelGoalsScoreNegative.hidden = true
        cell.LabelP.hidden = true
        cell.LabelP_GP.hidden = true
    }

    return cell

}
```

And it looks like this in the view:
[image: Horizontal iOS app]

I would really like to make the app like a normal HTML table, so it would look like this:
[image: Horizontal website]

But I really can´t figure out how to make a table in an iOS app.

I have looked at other posts on this topic on stack overflow, but they are usually written in objective c or you have to use a custom framework for it and they are usually not very responsive.

Can anyone help me with a simple table example in swift, that contains a header and data read from an array ?

Comment: You should try to solve the problem and show us your progress and where you got stuck. Requesting a full solution is not encouraged and you probably won't get any good answers.

Comment: Are you writing a Mac or iOS application? For both of these the answer will be different. Also what is your final purpose? Writing native graphical applications is quite different from the web technologies. As @EmilioPelaez has said, you should first try to solve the problem yourself and then ask a specific question. In any case you should either look into some UIKit (for iOS) or AppKit (MacOS) tutorials first.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. It is an iOS application. The final purpose is just to show a table with users and points in it. Could you share the link to good tutorial on this topic ? Because I have not been able to find a good one. My current solutions publish data to labels in a custom cell. It works but it is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the Collection view instead of tableview if you want to show the layout as you have shown in the image you can try this github demo 
https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout, 
I have used this in my project and it worked good and it looks like what you need

It is using `UICollectionViewLayout` to create the layout and show the based on the array

If you need the border as you have shown in the image you can give border to the `ContentCollectionViewCell` layer like this `contentCell.layer.borderWidth` and other properties of border

Comment: I have looked at my own solution, by using a webview and then loading the responsive HTML table from the website. I have also added a back button to the webview. It works but it gives a bad mix between native app and a webview that I do not like. 

So I ended up using your suggestion with the CustomCollectionViewLayout. I still have to change the code so it shows more tables when in landscape mode and then I hope to change the styling so it will look a bit better. I still don´t understand why it has to be so difficult to make a table in an iOS app. But that´s just me :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code can give you solutions, you might need to customise it and you can also use the Objective-C files in swift using bridging header file

http://www.code4app.net/ios/A-customizable-Web-like-multi-column-table-view-for-iOS-with-header-and-inner-ro/54052f24e24741bf5df2ba2f